# Как разделить строку пополам?

Tags: php, строки

```
$var = '+7 (4852) 13-24-31'
```

Добрый день, есть такой вывод строки из БД, через `strlen($var)`, узнал что у нее 18 символов
Как мне разделить данную строку, чтобы получить в одной переменной 9 символов и в другой 9 символов.

Comment: `$arr = str_split($var, 9);`

Comment: `$arr = str_split($var, round(strlen($var) / 2));`

Comment: ну давайте еще скажем, что `[$start, $end] = ...`